# Alias for knockout control not working

Tags: html, knockout.js

This is view

```
<ul class="container-full" data-bind="foreach:  { data: notificationDetail, as: 'notification' }">
            <li class="odd">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <p data-bind="text:notification.notificationTime"></p>
                        <span data-bind="text: notification.notificationSubject"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell width-60px text-center">
                        <img src="/ebms/app/public/spa/styles/images/icon-remove.png" /> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Initialise function:

```
function initializeView(notificationList) {
            var notificationDetails=new Array();
            if (notificationList) {
                this.notification = notificationList.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < notificationList.length; i++) {
                    var notification = notificationList[i];
                    notificationDetails.push(notification);
                }
                this.notificationDetail = notificationDetails;
            }
        }
```

this.notificationDetail = ko.observableArray([]);

this.notificationDetail: this.notificationDetail: Array[2]
0:Object
NoNotification:"05"
NotificationSubject:"Notification sub line 1"
NotificationTime:"14 May 2016   9.00PM"

Comment: notification.notificationTime doesn't return data

Comment: Your markup looks fine .Problem is with your viewModel.Try debugging it.

Comment: as I debug notificationDetail shows data as                        -this.notificationDetail: Array[2]                                                               -0:Object                                                                        ---NoNotification:"05"                                          NotificationSubject:"Notification sub line 1"                   NotificationTime:"14 May 2016 9.00PM"

Comment: would be helpful to figure out if you put your code in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do above 'alias' might not be required and you can directly bind the observables instead.